# Как попасть в файловую систему Docker-контейнера Focalboard?

Tags: docker

Всем привет!
Установил официальный docker-контейнер с Focalboard и отдельный том для сохранения информации после перезапуска контейнера. Возникла проблема, что один из пользователей забыл пароль, а для его сброса надо запустить скрипт внутри контейнера.
`docker exec -it 3199d9b578d2 bash` выдаёт ошибку *OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown*. Замена `bash` на `sh` результата также не дала. Может кто сталкивался с этой проблемой на данном контейнере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Focalboard` основан на distoless образах (в данном случае `gcr.io/distroless/base-debian10`) в которых нет ни `bash`, ни `sh`. Т.е. это минимальные образы, которые содержат все необходимое для запуска и работы приложения.

[Тут](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/main/base/README.md) описано что входит в base образ:

- ca-certificates
- A /etc/passwd entry for a root user
- A /tmp directory
- tzdata
- glibc
- libssl
- openssl

Насколько я понял, чтобы сбросить пароль в `Focalboard` нужно сделать запрос в `focalboard_local.socket` (скрипт который я нашел, делает это через `curl`). Можете попробовать перезапустить контейнер и примонтировать этот сокет в хост систему и сделать запрос из неё.